# Fiware: how to secure the communication between Orion and Cygnus?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

How can we secure the communication between Orion and Cygnus?
How can we use cygnus with a protected Orion (pep is deployed above Orion broker)?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of securing Orion->Cygnus communications:

1. Co-locate Orion and Cygnus in the same host, so all comunication are through localhost network interface (this solution assumes that the host itslef is properly secured, of course).
2. Using a firewall (e.g. iptables) so Cygnus port can be reached only from the IP where Orion runs.
3. Using HTTPS notifications. In order to use this option take into account that:

   - Cygnus should be able to receive notifications in HTTPS. I'm not fully sure about Cygnus capabilities with this regards, but my colleague @frb could provide more detail.
   - You need [Rush](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/admin/rush/index.html) to send notifications in HTTPS with Orion.

You can also explore the posibility of using a PEP proxy for Cygnus. You only need to secure one operation at Cygnus: `POST /v1/notifyContext`. Have a look to the [PEP official documentation](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/pep-proxy-wilma).

**UPDATE:** since verion 1.7.0, Orion implements native HTTPS notifications (i.e. without needing Rush).

Comment: Thanks for your response, concerning the deployment of Orion and cygnus in the same machine: is it recommended to do so or it is better that they will be in a separate machines and why?

Comment: In general is a good idea to colocate both. Only in the case the expected load is too high to cope in just one host or if you need independent tiers for horizontal scaling Orion and/or Cygnus separately makes sense to have them in separate machines.